# wordpress login.php redirects to weird places after site was hacked

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I am trying to de-hack my wordpress blog, and get it working again. I managed to get the homepage (without a theme). When I try to login into the site (to get my admin access), I see that it redirects to a new url that has nothing to do with my site.

so for example I manage to get to the login page directly:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog/login.php
```

but when I put my username and password and press the login button I am redirected to:

```
old.mydomain.bob/login.php
```

which doesn't exist (obviously)

I am working on wordpress 4.0.10, and try to understand what has happened and how to fix it. eventually, I might reinstall and hope that the database will be fine - but still. try to find what's going on.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that the database is fine; you don't know what the hackers have done (they may have added a new admin user, for example, or added javascript to your pages.  See [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) on what to do.  As for your specific problem, check your `.htaccess` file (if it's been changed you'll need to update it anyway for your reinstall).  If it's unchanged, `old.mydomain.bob` is almost certainly in the database (possible obfuscated); go for a clean install.

Comment: Pls check your database .. export the sql file and search for old domain old.mydomain.bob and replace with new one .. also check ur htaccess file